# Obliquity-Induced Hadley Cell Reversal

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, weather, seasons, axial-tilt

My planet has an axial tilt around 50° and a day length around 3 earth days. Under these conditions two things should occur:

1: There should be one large cell per hemisphere.

2: This cell should reverse direction during the summer(ground level winds in the northern hemisphere switching from going southwest to going northeast).

Now, my question is: **Will the cell experiencing winter also flip? Or will it only switch in summer?**

The prior makes sense because of the interaction with the other cell, but the latter also makes sense as the equator is still warmer than the winter pole.

Comment: Where does the summer switching one switch from?

Comment: @L.Dutch - Reinstate Monica♦ What exactly are you refering to? The northern cell (a hadley cell) experiences ground level winds that travel from northeast to southwest, but during the northern summer, switches to flowing from southwest to northeast. Sorry, if that isn't what you're asking about.

Comment: The summer cells reverses direction during summer, per your statement. Then it has to come from a winter state, or not?

Comment: @L.Dutch - Reinstate Monica♦Ah, my question is about what the winter cell does, but I'd imagine the summer cell switches fron a kind of spring/vernal system. Basically, the cell either behaves normally in all seasons aside fron summer, or there are summer/winter wind patterns and spring/autumn wind patterns. Does that make sense, or am I loosing it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not really sure you get only one cell per hemisphere but as I can't prove it wrong I will take it as given for my answer.
I think you won't get a switch in the cell, but your cells will expand and shrink from summer to winter, so 'winter-cell' is bigger then 'summer-cell' and even crossing the equator. We can already view this expanding and shrinking in the headley-cell on our earth (in our case it can't really cross the equator because of our much less axial tilt). Your switch is not as plausible because of the following problem:
If one cell switches directions, adjacent cells have also to switch, because the Areas of rising air of one cell and falling air of the other can not be at the same place, directions of adjacent cells are different at every time. So if summer on one hemisphere would switch both your cells, summer on the other hemisphere would do the same and by that you would stay in the switched state all the time. Especially you would have a winter-cell with air flowing from cold to hot. Thats not realy plausible. The border of both cells wandering with the sun would be more feasible.